# Nodejs write files

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with `nodejs`. Im now making a server that will serve the files requested by the users. What I did:

- I get the path
- find the file (`fs.exists()`)
- If the path is a file get the stream
- stream.pipe (response)

The problem now is that I want that the user download the file, but if I write a .txt file, the pipe method write the content of the file in the browser... So, I tried with a .pdf, but in this case the web page keep loading and nothing happen... Can someone help?

```
if(exists) {

        response.writeHead(302, {"Content-type":'text/plain'});

        var stat = fs.statSync(pathname);

        if(stat.isFile()) {
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(pathname);
            stream.pipe(response);
        } else {
            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-type":'text/plain'});
            response.end()
        }


        //response.end();

} else {
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-type":'text/plain'});
        response.write("Not Found");
        response.end()
}
```

Comment: welcome, you should add the code. then SO can help you. thanks

Comment: Have a look at [`express`'s `sendfile`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile). It also does the content-type handling for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your `if` case you always set the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain`, that's why your browser shows your text file inline. And for your PDF, `text/plain` is just the wrong one, it should be `application/pdf`, so you need to set the type dynamically.

If you want the browser to enforce a download, set the following headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your filename…"
Content-Type: text/plain (or whatever your content-type is…)
```

Basically, this is what [Express's res.download](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download) function does as well internally, so this function may be worth a look as well.

Comment: Nice it works, thank you. But I cant use setHeader and the write the header right?

Comment: I mean, can you specify that when you do response.writeHeader()?

Answer (score 1):

well, looks like the problem is that the pdf content type isnt `text/plain`.

Replace the content type to `application/pdf`

like:

```
response.writeHead(302, {"Content-type":'application/pdf'});
```

More info here:  http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types and http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778.txt